# Selecting null columns for script output in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I need to output 3 null columns in my SQL statement, i'm using SQL developer Oracle 11g
For example:

```
SELECT
  c.CID, 
  c.CName,
  null, 
  null, 
  null, 
  r.RegionID, 
  r.RegionName
FROM
  Regions r 
  INNER JOIN Branch b ON b.RegionID = r.RegionID
  INNER JOIN Countries c ON c.CID = b.CID;
```

So in the script output/query result window on SQL Developer shows

```
  CID| CName | Null |   Null  | Null | RegionID  | RegionName
  ------------------------------
  C1 | ENG   | Null  | Null   | Null | R1        | UK   
  C2 | ...   | Null  | Null   | Null | R2        | ...
  C3 | ...   | Null  | Null   | Null | R3        | ...
```

What would be ideal is if i could do something like:

```
Select
Country,
Region, 
Null as Continent,
Null as hemisphere

etc
```

I know this may sound bonkers but it's just for formatting purposes until the database is updated.

EDIT: Thanks for that, didn't realize it was so straight forward, the only issue is my null column is massive on the script output screen, even though it's empty, is there a way make it a more reasonable size?

Comment: using the syntax `Null as NameOfColumn` works perfectly.

Comment: Check my answer for an example - you have to `CAST` the `NULL` as, for example, `VARCHAR2(1)`. Then it will take less space.

Comment: Genius, thanks Przemyslaw!  Just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it just the way you presented...:

```
SELECT
  c.CID, 
  c.CName,
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR2(1)) AS Continent, 
  null AS hemisphere, 
  null AS something, 
  r.RegionID, 
  r.RegionName
FROM
  Regions r 
  INNER JOIN Branch b ON b.RegionID = r.RegionID
  INNER JOIN Countries c ON c.CID = b.CID;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great for the Query Result window, though in the Script Output window the null columns are huge, many times larger than the entire database, despite being empty.  Any way to fix that?

Comment: @Hulaz Yes, check my edited answer for an example - you have to `CAST` the `NULL` as, for example, `VARCHAR2(1)`. Then it will take less space.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that should work.

```
SELECT
  c.CID, 
  c.CName,
  null AS country, 
  null AS Region, 
  null AS hemisphere, 
  r.RegionID, 
  r.RegionName
FROM
  Regions r 
  INNER JOIN Branch b ON b.RegionID = r.RegionID
  INNER JOIN Countries c ON c.CID = b.CID;
-- Or, if you don't have any tables yet:
SELECT
  NULL AS CID, 
  NULL AS CName,
  NULL AS country, 
  NULL AS Region, 
  NULL AS hemisphere, 
  NULL AS RegionID, 
  NULL AS RegionName
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by showing null u mean that basically it should be empty and shown as null so u can use the query below:

```
Select
Country,
Region, 
''  Continent,
''  hemisphere,
from 
regions r;
```